# NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass) Post Attachments issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting this error and I am not sure why.  My post is still saved to the database, even though it throws and error.  It has something to do with the post_attachments, but I am not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my PostController create method with the error:

```
def create
    @trail = Trail.find(params[:trail_id])
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params.require(:post).permit(:body, post_attachments_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :gallery]))
    @post.trail = @trail
    @new_post = Post.new
    authorize @post

if @post.save
  params[:post_attachments]['gallery'].each do |a|  
    @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:gallery => a, :post_id => @post.id)
  end
  flash[:notice] = "Post was saved!"
  redirect_to @post.trail
else
  flash[:error] = "Error creating the post. Please try again."
  render :new
end
```

end

The error occurs on the line `params[:post_attachments]['gallery'].each do |a|`

Comment: `params[:post_attachments]` is nil.

Comment: @messanjah , yes, but how do I fix that?